# How does the Three Tier architectural style works? Some handy example

Tags: java, architecture, software-design, three-tier

I have been provided with a Java Application on which to apply the Three-Tier architectural style; One of the use cases to do is the **login**. 
I've studied all the theory and rules that apply to this architectural style, but I need to understand the logic of  the objects co-operation between the various levels and how patterns work together on each level to realize this (and the others) use case.

First, I've created the three basical packages: **Presentation**, **Application** and **Data**. In addition, I included one more package about the **Boundary** classes, The various GUIs from which requests will be sent.

In the Presentation layer, I just put a *Front Controller*, that encapsulates the presentation logic required by clients using the application.

In the Data layer, I put a *DatabaseConnection* class (Class that communicates with the database and that is responsible for loading the driver, connecting to the database, querying etc.) and *DAOs classes* (Data Access Object, that interfaces with the database).

The real problem is that I don't know what to put in the Application level, which represents the main part of the application, defining the domain model of the application, that is: their entities, their relationships, and application logic. It should not contain any reference to how the data will be presented to the user or how they will be saved.

So, I currently have this hierarchy:

Main ---> **Boundary** > **Presentation** > **Application** > **Data** > **Database**

In accordance with this architecture, how can I make a simple login?
Bearing in mind that each level can communicate ONLY with the underlying level; 
For example, a class in Boundary layer cannot comunicate directly with a class in Data layer, Boundary's classes can comunicate with Presentation's classes only.
If necessary, you can post a pseudocode, which makes the idea of the steps to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Boundary** calls only basic methods on the **Presentation**layer.

Let's say the User clicks a Button to create a User the flow would be the following: **Boundary** calls method `createUser(String name, int age)` on the FrontController (**Presentation**layer). The Controller can check some basic (UI-Related) things and would then call a similar method on the **Application**layer.

The **Application**layer can now process some further checks (for example: is the Current Active User allowed to create a User?). The **Application**layer takes the given informationen (name and age), creates a DAO based on that and invokes the method to create the User on the **Data**layer (DAO).

The **Data**layer simply inserts the given information.

Comment: Your comment has been helpful, but I would like something more rigorous.
So, using the same logic, I wanna do a login. 
I've the boundary of the login class, called *B_Login* with two textarea and one button. When I press the button, I send a request to the FrontController that loads the driver, set the connection and calls the method dispatch(String request, Arraylist params); then? What happen between the Application layer and the Data layer? For example, if in the Application layer I've a Business Object, Transfer Object or Application Service, How do I keep logging in?

Comment: The Connection should not be set in the FrontController. Such an information is too specific and belongs in the Applicationlayer or even Datalayer. The Applicationlayer should check if the given Values (Username and Password) are valid (for example an empty String could already rejected here, without even really trying to Login).

Comment: Thank you very much about these tips, I will try to follow them accurately.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope I didn't say something wrong, if someone sees my answer and thinks I told something wrong feel free to tell me or add an answer.

Comment: Just a little clarification: as I said, I created two Packages: Boundary and Presentation, just to put some order between the views and the requests handled by the Front Controller. Now, if I wanna do a login, as we said, I call the method dispatch(String request, Arraylist params), the question is: Could I declare, in the boundary, a LoginTO? Because Transfer Objects are in the Application layer and they just trasports data between the Presentation and the Integration Tier; just because I could have put the boundaries inside the Presentation package, but, as I said, I wanted to put order.

Comment: For me the Boundary and the FrontController are both part of the Presentation, so it is ok to use Parts of the Applicationlayer (or, like to TO something thats between those two) in the Boundary.

Comment: Well done, so if I want to check that there are no empty fields in the textareas, who deals this control? The Business Object class?
In according to the architectural style, would it be wrong to do something like this in the boundary ActionPerformed method?

    if(jTextFieldLogin.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") ||     jTextFieldPassword.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "compile both textareas");
   }

Comment: What is the best choice? Control in the boundary (with the code I wrote in the last comment) or control in the Application Layer by using a LoginBusinessObject?

Comment: An empty Check can be done in the boundary, but nothing more specific. Example if it was a registration: Boundary checks if typed Email is possibly an email, application layer checks if that email is already registered

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/front_controller_pattern.htm What do you think about this kind of Front Controller? How can I modify it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148182/discussion-between-rollback-and-zoythrus).

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for you

Comment: I've a few doubts that I would like to clarify as soon as possible. I'm sorry to bother you all the time, but with this architectural style I'm a beginner. Regarding the login use case only: I've declared a LoginTO in the Boundary of Login. I filled it with username & password and I send (The LoginTO) to the FrontController. Then, if I haven't Business classes about the login, How can I resolve it? Because I cannot declare a DAO in the Boundary.